# Я из Батманов или из Батман?

Tags: склонение, топонимика, множественное-число

Подскажите, пожалуйста, ответ на такой вопрос. Есть такое село Батманы. Как будет правильно в родительном падеже?

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Не поняла про существительные на Н, Как понять на Н?

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что правильно: ***из Батманов.***

Например: [Расстояние от Москвы до Батманов](https://routes.votpusk.ru/distance.asp?from=faaff0f0-d343-4ad6-b24e-4b6f564f3a9b&to=e8628135-caad-4f86-a8a8-d0cc52c7d779) ~ 425 км.

А это здесь обозначено склонение известного села [Тарханы](https://routes.votpusk.ru/route.asp?i=3379068). Усадьба М.Ю. Лермонтова.

**И просто на слух** форма с окончанием ОВ подходи больше. Дело в том, что нулевое окончание часто имеют существительные на Н, называющие **национальность**: армяне, грузины, осетины, цыгане, англичане, также крестьяне. Поэтому кажется, что "из Батман" — это тоже указание национальности.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (ответ на вопрос из комментария)

1. Имеется в виду **сонорный звук** Н в основе, например суффикс АНИН/ЯНИН: англичанин/англичане/англичан. Мы же никогда не скажем: крестьянов, англичанов, дворянов,  для нас это фонетически неприемлемо.

Вообще говоря, сущ. в форме мн. числа Р.п.  могут иметь три вида окончаний: **ОВ/ЕВ, ЕЙ, нулевое окончание.**  Для сущ. м. рода 2 скл. основным является окончание ОВ/ЕВ, но наблюдается устойчивое колебание (выбор нулевого окончания). Это характерно для слов определенной тематики (национальности, виды войск, парные предметы, единицы измерения, названия овощей/фруктов).

2. А теперь обратимся **к этимологии**, почему село так назвали? Вто [статья](https://dzen.ru/a/YaDMy60K0BWVg5AZ) на эту тему. ***Батманы*** – старинное торговое село в Кинешемском районе. Расположено оно на территории, где исстари занимались сапоговаляльным промыслом, т.е. попросту говоря, делали валенки. Топоним ***батман*** – старинная азиатская весовая единица, входившая в русскую систему мер, которая, вероятно, и дала название селу.
3. Итак, будем считать, что в основе названия лежит  **батман** — азиатская весовая единица. И вот для этой группы характерно колебание: грамм/граммов, ампер/амперов и т.д. В результате закрепляется  один вариант, а  второй  не нормируется или считается разговорным. Это мы видим и в данном случае: ***Батманов*** и ***Батман.*** Один из вариантов считается более приемлемым и правильным, но какой? Это уже традиция, чем-либо обоснованная и закрепленная в речи и на письме.
4. Сравним: грамм и граммов. **ГРАММ**, -а; мн. род. граммов и грамм; м. [франц. gramme] Единица массы в метрической системе мер, одна тысячная доля килограмма. На первом месте в словаре указана нейтральная (книжная) форма, а грамм — разговорный вариант.

В топонимике, вероятно, такая же **ситуация:** здесь в  письменной речи используется форма Р.п. ***из Батманов,*** а вторая форма (**из Батман**) будет разговорной. В то же время ситуация может меняться со временем. (Вот такие выводы мы делаем, когда рассуждаем **о правильном и неправильном:** всё в этих рассуждениях относительно и более правильно для «здесь и сейчас», а не правильно «вообще и всегда».)

5. И о восприятии **не слух**. Представим, что мы первый раз слышим название и ничего не знаем о его происхождении. *Я из Батманов* (основное окончание *ОВ*) больше похоже на **топоним**, чем *из Батман.* Ведь можно предположить существование небольшой национальности *батмане*, и тогда понять так: я (по национальности) из батман.

Comment: Викисловарь за "Батманов".

Comment: @Серж Совсем не обязательно, что склоняется так же, как единица измерения.

Comment: Единица измерения тут ни при чем. Это всего лишь вариант того, как можно объяснить происхождение названия. Но сейчас речь не об этом, а о корректном письменном варианте названия в настоящее время (как пишется в официальных документах). А в разговорной речи существуют оба варианта.

Comment: @oleedd, действительно, единица измерения тут ни при чем.

Comment: @Серж Тогда что вы нашли в Викисловаре?

Comment: @Sharon Не уверен. Есть названия, оба варианта родительного падежа которых используются (чтобы по количеству употреблений не смахивало на ошибку)? Как-то сомнительно.

Comment: Сомнительна ваша версия о двух равноправных названиях в  официальной  документации для конкретного населенного пункта.  Да что там официальная документация –  даже в расписании автобусов не будут использовать два разных названия. А в разговорной речи они существуют – две вариантные формы Р.п. встречаются в различных темах, такова особенность языка.

Comment: @Sharon Это не моя версия, а ваша. Я за разговорную речь, о которой вы говорите. *две вариантные формы Р.п. встречаются в различных темах* — чтобы так судить, надо не пара случаев, а несколько десятков. Вроде не встречал, чтобы было "-ов" (про похожие названия). Надо у жителей населённых пунктов спросить, как они говорят. Не думаю, что по-разному. Это очень вряд ли.

Comment: Поэтому приведите название, чтобы в Нацкорпусе или т.п. было много и того и того (ведь вы и за художественный стиль говорили). Сомневаюсь, что такое есть.

Answer (score 2):

[Батманы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B) — небольшие населенные пункты в Ивановской области (около 300 человек) и в Пермском крае (около сотни).
В малоиспользуемых топонимах иногда сложно определить правильное склонение.
При выборе "из Батман" я ориентировалась на следующие примеры.

• В рассказах Галины Кораблевой "Батманы по-русски" написано так:

> В детстве мы любили приезжать сюда из Кинешмы на маленьком автобусе. Он доезжал **до Батман**, а дальше, к Сидоровской, мы шли пешком через поле, через мостик, рощу.
> <...>
> Подкоп задумался, дети радовались, получалось, что вся страна вышла **из Батман**.

• Мне вспомнились украинские Бережаны.
Посмотрела: *из Бережан* — 1780, из Бережанов — 145.

*Команда **из Бережан** перебазировалась в Тернополь* (Е. Казаков. История чемпионатов СССР по футболу).
*13-й стрелковый корпус занял Станислав и Калуш, пленив 11-тысячную сводную группировку, следовавшую **из Бережан** к румынской границе* (В. Бешанов. Красный блицкриг).

• О Тарханах
*Смерть хозяина не изменила бытового уклада **Тархан*** (А. Марченко. Лермонтов).
*С. А. Раевскому (16 января 1836 г. **Из Тархан** в Петербург)* (письмо Лермонтова).
*Когда молодая почувствовала себя беременною, она отправилась с мужем и матерью **из Тархан** в Москву...* (Коллектив авторов. Жизнь и смерть Лермонтова).

Answer (score 1):

> Есть такое село Батманы. Как будет правильно в родительном падеже?

Если верить Википедии, ударение в названии этого села падает на второй слог: ***Батма́ны.***

Такое же ударение и в названии Тархан: ***Тарха́ны.***

Название Тарханы присутствует в «**Грамматическом словаре**» у Зализняка. Склонение этого названия по Зализняку выглядит так:

*Тарханы, **Тархан,** Тарханам,  Тарханы, Тарханами, о Тарханах.*

**Форма родительного падежа «(из) Тархан» поддерживается и большинством примеров из Гугл-книг:**

*Молодые выехали **из Тархан** в Москву, когда состояние здоровья Марьи Михайловны этого потребовало.*

*Это дало ей возможность, как и пишет Лермонтов, весной 1836 г. переехать **из Тархан,** где она жила с 25 июля 1835 г., в Петербург.*

*Предстояло ехать **из Тархан** в Корсаевку (верст 40) на свадьбу двоюродного брата Сережи…*

**Предположительно, аналогично Тарханам склоняется и название села Батманы.**

Примеры из Гугл-книг:

*Артистов и спортсменов **из Батман** знают во всех уголках района.*

*— Очень признателен учительнице  Маргарите Владимировне Кисляковой **из Батман.***

Answer (score 0):

**Дополнительный ответ, или попытка порассуждать**

• Я действительно первый раз слышу название населенного пункта (а их два) и ничего не знаю о его происхождении.
Зато я хорошо знаю, и многие знают, что такое [батман](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD) (батманы, батманов).
*Я из Батманов* — нет, мне не нравится.
При танцевальных и "ногоподнимательных" ассоциациях лучше все-таки звучит "из Батман".

> • Ведь можно предположить существование небольшой национальности *батмане*, и тогда понять так: я (по национальности) из батман.

А почему именно *батма**не***, а не *батма**ны***?
Мне такое предположение, такая придумка больше нравится. Тем более что это возможно.

Посмотрела [национальный состав России](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8) (194) и обнаружила следующие народности, оканчивающиеся на ***-ны*** (при склонении — на ***-ов***):
табасараны (табасаранов), туркмены (туркмен и туркменов), эвены (эвенов), финны (финнов), пуштуны (пуштунов), ительмены (ительменов), хваршины (хваршинов), нганасаны (нганасан и нганасанов), русины (русинов), сваны (сванов).

При склонении *батманы (батманов)* уже совсем не кажется, что "из Батман" — это указание на национальность. Наоборот, теперь можно понять так: я (по происхождению) из батманов.

Comment: БАТМАН, -а; м. [от франц. battement - биение, удар]. В классическом балете: группа движений и упражнение для ног (вытягивание, резкое или плавное поднимание ноги и т.п.). Большой б. (резкое поднятие прямой ноги вверх).  Похоже на спец. термин, не все его знают. Здесь важно обозначить письменный официальный вариант названия,  а в разговорной и художественной речи могут использоваться оба варианта. Это кому что нравится.